# Calling a function on page click

Tags: jquery

There are 2 buttons on a page, i.e `play` and `stop`. The `video` plays on load and shows the `stop` button. Clicking on the `stop` button will stop the video and show the `play` button.

```
var videoMode = false,
    videoModeSelector = '#intro .mouse, #intro .content, .slider.fullscreen .overlay';
$(window).load(function () {
    $(videoModeSelector).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        queue: false,
        complete: function () {
            if (!videoMode) {
                $('.slider').unmuteYTPVolume();
                $('<div />').appendTo('#intro').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    bottom: '30px',
                    color: '#FFF',
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    opacity: 0
                }).addClass('click-to-exit');
                $('<i />').appendTo('.click-to-exit').addClass('fa fa-volume-off');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.click-to-exit').animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, {
                        duration: 500,
                        queue: false,
                        complete: function () {}
                    });
                }, 500);
            }
            videoMode = true;
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
$that.click(function (evt) {
    if (videoMode && $(evt.target).is('.fa-volume-off')) {
        $('.slider').muteYTPVolume();
        $(videoModeSelector).show().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            queue: false
        });
        $that.find('.click-to-exit').hide();
        videoMode = false;
    } else {
        $('.slider').unmuteYTPVolume();
        $(videoModeSelector).show().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            queue: false
        });
        $that.find('.click-to-exit').show();
        videoMode = true;
    }
});
```

It's working fine. Now I want to add the click function on the page. When click on the page, the video stops and shows the `play` button, but the `play` button is not functioning. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
$(document).click(function () {
    if (videoMode) {
        $('.slider').muteYTPVolume();
        $('.click-to-exit').hide().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            queue: false
        });
        $(videoModeSelector).show().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            queue: false
        });
        videoMode = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your play button is a sub-part of the "document". So, the below code overrides all other elements' click event handler.

```
$(document).click(function(  if ( videoMode )  {
            $( '.slider' ).muteYTPVolume( );
            $( '.click-to-exit' ).hide( ).animate( { opacity: 0 }, { duration: 500, queue: false } );
            $( videoModeSelector ).show( ).animate( { opacity: 1 }, { duration: 500, queue: false } );            
            videoMode = false;
        }
    });
```

You may straight-forward wrap this handling into a condition like :

```
if ( videoMode )  {
   $(document).click(function( ){
            $( '.slider' ).muteYTPVolume( );
            $( '.click-to-exit' ).hide( ).animate( { opacity: 0 }, { duration: 500, queue: false } );
            $( videoModeSelector ).show( ).animate( { opacity: 1 }, { duration: 500, queue: false } );            
            videoMode = false;

    });
}
```

Comment: Try to give details! Also, check the browser console for apt error msgs

Comment: its whole website, still confusing me :(

Answer (score 0):

this function is working fine
but again you click on play button this function calls :(

```
                $(document).click( function(e) {
                if(videoMode){
                    $( videoModeSelector ).show().animate( { opacity: 1 }, { duration: 500, queue: false } );
                    $that.find( '.click-to-exit' ).show().animate( { opacity: 0 }, { duration: 500, queue: false, } );
                    $( '.slider' ).muteYTPVolume( );
                } 
            });
```